# Spring Boot + Angular Render Photos Which Received From Server

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I want to users can send photos to server and then recive and see them on browser.

This is my endpoint when creating entities:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.POST,
            consumes = {"multipart/form-data"})
    @ResponseBody
    public void create(
            @RequestPart("actor") @Valid ActorDto actorDto,
            @RequestPart("file") @Valid MultipartFile file
            ) {

            String actorProfilePhotoLocation = fileService.saveActorProfile(file);
            Actor actor = converter.convertToEntity(actorDto, actorProfilePhotoLocation);
            actorService.create(actor);

    }
```

When I recive the data, I am writing photos with file system not with database.

Here:

```
public String saveActorProfile(MultipartFile file, ActorDto actorDto) {
    String fileName = System.currentTimeMillis()
            + "." + this.getFileExtension(file.getOriginalFilename());

    File directory = new File(ACTOR_DIRECTORY);

    if(!directory.exists()) {
        directory.mkdirs();
    }


    try {
        byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
        Path path = Paths.get(ACTOR_DIRECTORY + "//" + fileName );
        Files.write(path, bytes);

        return path.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("FileService::saveActorProfile has failed." +
                " With parameters: "
        + " file: " + file
        + " message: " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

This part is okay I don't any problem with this. But when I sent photos to client, client can not see photos because I am sending it as a byte array.

This is my dto:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class ActorDto {

    private Long actorId;

    private String name;

    private String surname;

    private String description;

    private List<HeroDto> heroList;

    private Byte[] photoBuffer;

}
```

Angular and Spring Boot working at different ports, their application contexts are different. So I can't serve photos like static context.

I am trying to send photos as I read from disk.

Here:

```
  public ActorDto convertToDto(Actor source) throws IOException {

        ActorDto dto = modelMapper.map(source, ActorDto.class);
        byte[] photo = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(source.getProfilePhotoPath()));
        dto.setPhotoBuffer(this.autoBoxingByteArray(photo));

        return dto;
    }
```

I am returning a dto list to GET request.

---

When client recieve the data I am trying to convert byte array to base64 string.
But the image is not showing.

Here:

```
export class Actor {
  actorId: number;
  name: string;
  surname: string;
  description: string;
  heroList: Hero[];
  photoBuffer: number[];
  photo: string;
}
```

And this is the converting part:

In my situation "`value.photoBuffer`" something like: `[-119, 80, 78,...]` so it's a number array.

"value.photo" is something like:  "`data:image/png;base64,LTExOQ==ODA=Nzg=NzE=MTM=MTA=MjY...`"

`src` attribute of `<img>` is : "`unsafe:data:image/png;base64,LTExOQ==ODA=Nzg=NzE=MTM=MTA=MjY...`"

```
manipulateReceivedData(actorList: Actor[]): void {
    const PNG_PREFIX = 'data:image/png;base64,';
    actorList.forEach((value: Actor, index: number, array: Actor[]) => {
      let photo = PNG_PREFIX;
      value.photoBuffer.forEach((byte: number, j: number, bytes: number[]) => {
        photo += btoa(byte.toString());
      });
      value.photo = photo; // Convert byte array to string that represent a image in base64;
    });
  }
```

IN

Html part:

```
            <div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let a of actorList">
              <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                <img class="card-img-top" [src]="a.photo" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-text text-center">{{a.name}} {{a.surname}}</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">{{a.description}}</p>
                  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

I can see image that uploaded by browser nicely in file system.
But I can't achieve to represent image in browser.

WHERE DID I GO WRONG?

And addiational question?
Let's say I have achive to represent image on browser. And I am trying to represent 50 image at the same time is this an issue about performance?

Comment: Why not make the images available from a URL from your backend? For browsers it's much more efficient to load images as resources then loading them from embedded binary string. Then if you request the images from your frontend your backend only has to return list of image urls in JSON format.

Comment: So you are saying serve the images as a static resource in Spring Boot.
But I am storing images in diffrent directory that completly independent from Spring Boot and Angular apps. How can I achive that do you know any example blog post or something?

Comment: Yes I suggest to serve them as 'static' resources. All you need to do is create a spring Controller that maps to an url like '/images/{relpath}' and the controller fetches the images based on the relative path from your 'local' filesystem. See http://www.baeldung.com/spring-controller-return-image-file for an example ow how ow to return binary data.

Comment: I read this [blog post](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-controller-return-image-file).
But it is eventually is same thing with what I do, Isn't it? Also I am returning image with additional data I mean that returned image is profile photo of someone so I should return json data about that person. Thanks you very much for your time. I think I am okay with my solition. And I liked it it's using application context to serve images but like I said I am using an independent location to store images. Thanks again Jeroen.

Answer (score 2):

Ohh blessed JavaScript and TypeScript. One of them encoding my byte array in a weird format I saw there is a lot of "`=`" sign. So I have tried to encode it in "Java" code and it's worked.

Here is code:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class ActorDto {

    private Long actorId;

    private String name;

    private String surname;

    private String description;

    private List<HeroDto> heroList;

    private String photo; // I have replaced byte array with String.

}
```

After I read the file as bytes.

I encoded it with Java.

```
public ActorDto convertToDto(Actor source) throws IOException {

        ActorDto dto = modelMapper.map(source, ActorDto.class);
        byte[] photo = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(source.getProfilePhotoPath()));

        StringBuilder base64 = new StringBuilder("data:image/png;base64,");
        base64.append(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(photo));
        dto.setPhoto(base64.toString());

        return dto;
    }
```

__

I deleted number array field from frontend model:

```
export class Actor {
  actorId: number;
  name: string;
  surname: string;
  description: string;
  heroList: Hero[];
  photo: string;
}
```

In html I have to pipe it because of "`unsafe`" prefix which Angular adds it on src attribute like "`unsafe:data:image/png;base64,...`" but It should be like "`data:image/png;base64,...`" otherwise image won't be shown.:

```
 <div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let a of actorList">
              <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                <img class="card-img-top" [src]="a.photo | safeUrl" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-text text-center">{{a.name}} {{a.surname}}</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">{{a.description}}</p>
                  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Here is the new added pipe:

```
@Pipe({name: 'safeUrl'})
export class SafeUrlPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer)  {}

  transform(value: any, ...args: any[]): any {

    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(value);

  }

}
```

And It'is worked. Now I can see Images on browser.

But I am still confused about performance. Is it a true solition in order to fetch and show images from server? I am not sure but at least it's working.